# How can I get the current page number from PDF opened in Chrome using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf, web

I'm developing a **Javascript code** where I'm trying to access the **PDF current page number** but I can't get a successful answer.

**Is there a way I can access that page number easily?**

Or at least **access the HTML code** of the book opened with the Chrome PDF Viewer so I can access which page ***is-Active Painted***

**Example Image:**

[image]

Comment: Will your users always be using Chrome?